# Rerun execute_process on file change

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am looking for a way to get CMake to re-run a shell command every time it detects that the dependencies for a specific target/executable has changed. I tried adding a custom command the has a dependency on a target, but this does not seem to be doing the trick.

Example of what I thought might work:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
           OUTPUT temp
           DEPENDS my_Target
           COMMAND ./some_command.sh)
```

Any suggestions of a command that may be able to run a command when a dependency change has been detected for a target. Or even better if we can check for a change in specific files.

Comment: `some_command.sh` needs to actually be run before `my_target` is built. So yes temp will be a part of `my_target`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you might want this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(cmaketest)

add_custom_command(OUTPUT some_file.cpp
  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar.cpp 
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy 
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bar.cpp
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/some_file.cpp
  VERBATIM
)

add_executable(mn main.cpp some_file.cpp)
```

Put the output file in the source list of the target which depends on it.

Comment: What the command is supposed to do is run a script that auto generates code files. These code files are then to be added to a source list and used in a target. So can the argument for COMMAND be any cmake or bash command or does it have to follow a certain format?

Answer (score -3):

`add_custom_command()` uses simple check for `OUTPUT` file existence to determine if the command should be run. If it doesn't exist, then CMake do `make my_Target` and only then run your command. At the same time, if `OUTPUT` exist, CMake doesn't run anything at all.

To achieve what you want you need to `add_custom_target()` (probably with `ALL` keyword to run it with `make`) and implement checking for changes inside your `some_command.sh`.

Comment: `uses simple check for OUTPUT file existence to determine if the command should be run` it also checks that OUTPUT is older then any of the files/targets in DEPENDS. `If it doesn't exist, then CMake do make my_Target and only then run your command` nope, this command will be invoked only if OUTPUT is a part of some target, if there are no targets that use OUTPUT the command will never be triggered. `if OUTPUT exist, CMake doesn't run anything at all` see note above, it can run if OUTPUT is not fresh enough.

Comment: `implement checking for changes inside your some_command.sh` what's the point of checking in script if cmake can do it for you?